# How can I compel alphanumeric entries for username textbox on woocommerce registration form

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I am having a bit of a challenge with Woocommerce registration form. Currently, users are able to register using all numeric characters as their usernames. I can't think of a way to enforce that they use only alphanumeric combinations. Not only numbers. I can't seem to find any answers anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`woocommerce_registration_errors`](http://hookr.io/filters/woocommerce_registration_errors/) hook to validate the username & set an error if your conditions aren't met - WooCommerce will bail and pass the error back to the UI for the user:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_registration_errors', function ( WP_Error $errors, $username ) {
    if ( ! preg_match( '/[a-z]/i', $username ) ) {
        $errors->add( 'username', 'Username must contain alphabetic characters.' );
    }

    return $errors;
}, 10, 2 );
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your response. forgive me, but I am relatively intermediate with programming. Does this code chunk go into functions.php?

Comment: Yes you can pop it in your functions.php. If you want to get a bit more "fancy", pop it in a [MU plugin](https://codex.wordpress.org/Must_Use_Plugins) - this helps keep your logic separated from your theme.